# Criar um data.frame em branco para receber resultados?

Tags: r, data.frame

Suponha que você queira criar um quadro de dados em branco para receber os resultados de um teste de aderência.

```
x<-data.frame(Distribuicao=c(NULL),p-value=c(NULL))
```

Apos a realização do teste tem-se um vetor com os resultados:

```
res.ad<-c("Gumbel", 0.9105)
```

Para incluir o resultados do teste no quadro de dados utilizei `rbind`:

```
x<-rbind(x,res.ad)
```

No resultado, x perde-se os nomes das variáveis "Distribuição" e "p-value", e  x é:

```
XGumbel  X0.9105
 Gumbel   0.9105
```

Qual a melhor forma de armazenar estes resultados ou como posso contornar a questão dos nomes da variáveis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A forma que você está fazendo agora trará problemas.

Veja que quando você faz:

```
res.ad <- c("Gumbel", 0.9105)
```

Você está transformando o número em texto:

```
res.ad
[1] "Gumbel" "0.9105"
```

Então nessa parte o ideal seria você trabalhar também com um `data.frame`, por exemplo, `data.frame(Distribuição = "Gumbel", pvalue = 0.9105)`.

Dito isto, uma forma de juntar resultados neste caso é trabalhar com listas. Vá acumulando os resultados em uma lista e depois junte todas fazendo um `do.call` com `rbind`. Por exemplo:

```
set.seed(1) # apenas para tornar o exemplo reproduzível

lista <- list() # lista para armazenar resultados

for(i in 1:5){
  # salva resultados
  lista[[i]] <- data.frame(Distribuicao = sample(letters, 1), pvalue = runif(1))
}

# junta todos resultados
do.call("rbind", lista)
```

A parte do `do.call` com `rbind` pode ser substituída por funções de outros pacotes como a função `bind_rows` do `dplyr` ou `rbindlist` do `data.table`.